# Magento 1.9 Captcha disabled in advance but active in admin login - Can't Login

Tags: admin, configuration, login, captcha

Was letting a client play with their site and they didn't like the captcha. So I disabled it in the config/ advanced section but forgot to disable it in the admin and it was left on for admin logins.

Now when we try to login to the admin the captcha image doesn't show as expected but after entering in the correct username and password it then comes back with an invalid catcha error.

So we have no way of logging into the admin to either reactivate captcha or diable it for admin login.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:

I found the answer here...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169015/disable-captcha-on-admin-login-page-from-database-or-codebase-in-magento

Did the database changed, cleaned out the var cache & session folders via ftp and logged in :)